# Missing group in Python regex match result

Tags: python, regex

Consider this code snippet:

```
import re

m = re.match(r'(\d-\w){2,3}', r'1-a2-b')

m.group(0), m.group(1), m.groups()

('1-a2-b', '2-b', ('2-b',))
```

so m.group(0) returns the whole match as expected, but why m.group(1) returns just the second repetition '2-b'? where is the first repetition '1-a'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you provided the capturing group only for the token which exists before the repitition quantifier `{2,3}` (*greedy*) which in-turn captures only the last match. So include also the repitition quantifier or range quantifier inside the capturing group and the make the previous capturing group as non-capturing group or otherwise it would produce two groups. Try this,

```
((?:\d-\w){2,3})
```

This is exactly same as `(.)+` and `(.+)`

Comment: Maybe changed with Phyton3? The only way seems to use finditer or findall